# Frequecny of hours between two datetime series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, histogram

I am trying to capture the frequency of hours between two timestamps in a dataframe. For example, one row of data has '2022-01-01 00:35:00' and '2022-01-01 05:29:47'. I would like for frequency to be attributed to Hours 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

| Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:35:00 | 2022-01-01 05:29:47 |
| 2022-01-01 00:55:00 | 2022-01-01 05:00:17 |
| 2022-01-01 01:35:00 | 2022-01-01 06:26:00 |
| 2022-01-01 02:29:00 | 2022-01-01 04:25:17 |

I have been trying to capture the time delta between the two but have not been able to figure out counting the frequency of hours.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by frequency. With two times you can only get the timedelta between them. Where does frequency come into it?

Comment: i.e. you have a coffee shop and these times in the above table are times that customers are in your coffee shop. I want to know how many customers are in my store at a given hour. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Then a frequency would be how many customers enter (or leave) the shop per interval of time (e.g. hour). Is that what you're looking for? Or is it the capacity utilization on a fixed frequency time axis?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the hours and then calculate the delta:

```
import datetime
df['start_hour'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").hour for i in df['Start Time']]
df['end_hour'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").hour for i in df['End Time']]
df['delta'] = df['end_hour'] - df['start_hour']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['freq'] = df.apply(lambda x:[i + x['Start Time'].hour for i in list(range(x['End Time'].hour - x['Start Time'].hour)], axis=1)
```